# How do I approach the following integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate

$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}~dx$$

Comment: Tom: If you want to ask a new, different question, ask a new question, in a new thread. Please don't change the question that has already been answered to a different one.  It makes the answers below appear to not make sense, it is confusing for readers, and it won't help you get an answer.  I will edit back to the old version.  (Also, please consider sharing your thoughts on the problem while you are posting your new question if you choose to do so.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use Residue Theorem.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}dx=\Re\int_C\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}dz=\Re 2\pi iRes|_{z=i}=\Re 2\pi i\frac{e^{-1}}{2i}=\frac{\pi}{e}.$$

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

$$C_R:=[-R,R]\cup \Gamma_R:=\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;z=Re^{it}\,,\;0\le t\le \pi\,\,,\,\,R>0\}$$

$$\left|\;\int\limits_{\Gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}dz\;\right|\le \sup_{z\in\Gamma_R}\frac{e^{-R\sin t}}{R^2-1}R\pi\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;R\sin t>0$$

$$\int\limits_{-R}^R\frac{e^{ix}}{x^2+1}dx\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos t+i\sin t}{x^2+1}dx$$

$$\oint\limits_{C_R}f(z):=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}\,dz=2\pi iRes_{z=i}(f)=2\pi i\frac{e^{-1}}{2i}=\frac{\pi}{e}$$

Now put together the above, use Cauchy's Residue theorem and stuff.

Comment: +1 Nice sketch for the proof.

Answer (score 5):

Since the simplest route has already been taken, I'll take another. The function $x\mapsto e^{-|x|}$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, and it's Fourier transform is easily computed as
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}e^{-itx}\,dx& = \int_0^\infty e^{-x(1+it)}\,dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{x(1-it)}\,dx \\
& = \frac{1}{1+it} + \frac{1}{1-it} \\
& = \frac{2}{1+t^2}
\end{align}
$$
This Fourier transform is integrable. So by the Fourier inversion formula,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{1+t^2}e^{ixt}\,dt = 2\pi e^{-|x|}.
$$
Take $x = 1$ and divide both sides by $2$.

Comment: I guess I should note that this argument might be circular to a person who uses this Fourier transform to derive the inversion formula; I am not such a person, so it does not seem circular to me.

Comment: +1, but I think you mean "take $x=1$", not $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks Eric! I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Well that integral has poles at $z=i, -i$. You can integrate along a semicircle of radius $R>i$, use Cauchy's residue formula and let $R \rightarrow \infty$ and hope that the integral along the arc goes to $0$.

Comment: -1 It needs more than that.  The arc length goes as $\frac 1R$ so this would suggest the integral diverges logarithmically.  The oscillatory nature of cosine rescues this approach, but needs some justification.

Comment: Hmm, I might be wrong but here's what I got. The integral along the upper semicircle is given by $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{iRe^{it}cos(Re^{it})}{R^{2}e^{2it}+1} dt$, which should grow like $\frac{1}{R}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The length of the semicircle grows as $\pi R$ which you have lost.  Multiplying by that it doesn't go to $0$ any more.  I should have said $R$ instead of $\frac 1R$ in my last comment.

Comment: Okay, I really think I'm missing something now because I have that term in my integrand. If we call OP's integrand $f$, then the path in question is $\gamma (t)= Re^{it}$, so $\int _{\gamma} f dz = \int _{0}^{\pi} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$. Then we obtain the integrand I have, where the $iRe^{it}=\gamma ' (t)$ seems to be the arc length term you're talking about. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, hopefully this helps clarify things.

Comment: Either directly or using Jordan's Lemma, the integral on the semicircle goes to zero when $\,R\to\infty\,$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}\quad \quad \hat f(\xi)=\pi e^{-|\xi|}\\ \mathcal F[f(x)e^{inx}]=\hat f(\xi-n)$$
Note that $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, so $\hat f$ is continuous:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\lim_{\xi\to 0}\frac{e^{ix}}{1+x^2}e^{-ix\xi}\,\,\mathrm dx+\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\lim_{\xi\to 0}\frac{e^{-ix}}{1+x^2}e^{-ix\xi}\,\,\mathrm dx=\\ \frac{\pi}2\lim_{\xi\to0}(e^{-|\xi-1|}+e^{-|\xi+1|})=\frac{\pi}e$$