# calculating $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\;dx\ $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral, but I think I don't do something correctly.
I'm interested where my try failed, compared to other ways.

$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\;dx\ $

I tried in 2 ways:

I defined $\gamma = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 $, where $ \gamma_1 = [-R, R], \gamma_2 = R e^{it}, t \in [0, \pi] $, and letting R aproach infinity.
So the integral on $\gamma_2$ approaches zero, and by residue theorem, we see that
$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz = 2\pi i Res(f, i)  = 2\pi i \frac{cosz}{z+i} $.

Letting $ z=i$ does not give me the correct result, since $ \cos i = \frac{e + \frac{1}{e}}{2} $

The second way: by partial decomposition, I see that $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos z}{1+z^2}\;dx\ = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{i\cos z}{2(z+i)}\;dx\ + \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{-i\cos z}{2(z-i)}\;dx\ $$
and by Cauchy's theorem for integrals, the first integral is zero, and the latter is $ \pi i (-i) \cos i $, which is still not the correct result..

What do I miss here?

Comment: Here is a well known fact you can get by searching for 'Characteristic Function of Cauchy Disitribution': $e^{-|t|}=\frac  1{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx} \frac  1{1+x^{2}} dx$. You can take real parts on both sides to find an answer for your integral.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it. However, I'd appreciate if anyone notices what I did wrong in my answer...

Comment: I would like to help here, but I don't understand what is that you are trying to compute. You wrote (at the title and again at the first sentence of your post) that you intend to compute $\int\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$, but that means that you are trying to compute an antiderivative. Is that what you want? It doesn't look like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I approach the following integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333424/how-do-i-approach-the-following-integral). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861317/value-of-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-x1x2-dx?noredirect=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886746/why-does-this-function-and-contour-i-chose-not-work-in-solving-this-integral?noredirect=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002255/what-is-wrong-in-this-calculation-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-x1x2dx?noredirect=1.